# Error on Table Name

Tags: sql, sql-server

I got an error while writing a query to create a table in SQL Server 2008 R2.

My script:

```
CREATE TABLE transaction
(

);
```

The *table name* is according to my client's request so I can't change the *table name*. I could not figure it out why this name is not working.

The error is:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'transaction'.

Comment: `Transaction` is a keyword. If you want create a table called `Transaction`, do like `create table [transaction]..........`

Comment: See [SQL SERVER – Bad Practice of Using Keywords as an Object Name – Avoid Using Keywords as an Object](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/297748/SQL-SERVER-Bad-Practice-of-Using-Keywords-as-an-Ob) and tell your customer you cannot use such a table name - use something more useful, meaningful

Answer (score 1):

Bacause Transaction is a keyword you must delimit it with `[]` or `""`.

e.g. `CREATE TABLE [Transaction] (...)`

e.g  `CREATE TABLE "Transaction" (...)`

Note 1: You better not use keywords for identifiers.

Note 2: Double Quotes will work as long as the `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` is `ON` ([msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174393.aspx))